# Which peace offer did Hitler give to Great Britain in 1940?

Tags: world-war-two, hitler, churchill, peace-treaty

A few days ago, I finished reading John Lukacs' *Five days in London: May 1940*. I am puzzled by a passage of that book:

> When Hitler made his grand peace offer to England in his [speech of 19 July](http://www.ibiblio.org/pha/policy/1940/1940-07-19b.html), Churchill chose not to answer, asking Halifax to do so instead, which the foreign secretary calmly and coolly did.

My question is: *which* peace offer? The closest thing to a peace offer that I was able to find there was:

> In this hour I feel it to be my duty before my own conscience to appeal once more to reason and common sense in Great Britain as much as elsewhere. I consider myself in a position to make this appeal, since I am not the vanquished, begging favors, but the victor speaking in the name of reason. I can see no reason why this war must go on.

Is this the peace offer? Or did I miss something?

Also, what was Lord Halifax's reply?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That was the peace offer, it was essentially repeating a similar offer made in October 1939.

Halifax's reply is [here](http://www.ibiblio.org/pha/policy/1940/1940-07-22a.html). Its content isn't especially remarkable, although coming from Lord Halifax, who had proposed suing for peace in May, was important.